# How to prevent postgres database writes when pg_restore is in progress?

Tags: postgresql-9.3, pg-restore

I am doing database restore using pg_restore which is failing when database write happens when restore is in progress. The error is due to primary key sequence used by new insert to the table, which is already there in the backup file.

pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "test": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_pkey"

Is there any way to prevent writes to database when pg_restore is running ?

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: I guess you should not restore database data to a working database cluster.

Comment: Yes, I am restoring in new database. But by the time restore completes, audit entry is added to the database which is causing restore to fail.

Comment: See my answer bellow

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue by restoring to database with another name and once restore is complete renamed database to actual name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can restore the data this way:

1. Take the last auto inc number from data source.
2. Set the next value for the table to be current number + 1
3. Restore your database

Comment: I am not sure how to extract sequences from dump. May be I can have all sequences in separate file. Is there any way to dump all sequences in separate file using pg_dump ?